# c++ template parameter compiler can not deduce

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, std-function, template-argument-deduction

here is function to register.

```
template <typename ReqT, typename RespT>
bool RegisterCmdHandler(int cmd_id, std::function<int(int, const ReqT&, RespT&)> sync_handler) {
    // ... do something with sync_handler and register it for later callback
    return true;
}
```

and a specific handler to register:

```
int SomeHandler(int id, const Foo& req, Bar& resp) {
    // ... specific logic
}
```

now I want to apply the Handler to Register Function, compiler complains

```
RegisterCmdHandler(1, SomeHandler); // ERROR, compiler can not deduce
```

while specificly write out the type is OK:

```
RegisterCmdHandler<Foo, Bar>(1, SomeHandler); // OK, compiler can deduce
```

but the latter has ugly API. How can I get the first on work?

Comment: TL;DR: Templates never do conversions.  `SomeHandler` is not a `std::function`, so it can't deduce the type of `std::function`.

Comment: @NathanOliver The suggested duplicate questions do not answer "How can I get the first on work?".

Comment: *If* you intend only to use ordinary functions, you could use a function pointer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the first on work?

Add an overload for plain function pointers:

```
template <typename ReqT, typename RespT>
bool RegisterCmdHandler(int cmd_id, int(*sync_handler)(int, const ReqT&, RespT&)) {
    std::function<int(int, const ReqT&, RespT&)> sync_handler2(sync_handler);
    return RegisterCmdHandler(cmd_id, sync_handler2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the first on work?

I see some ways.

(1) If you can modify the `RegisterCmdHandler()` function **and** you don't need to know, inside it, what types `ReqT` and `RestT` are, I suggest you to avoid at all `std::function` and accept `sync_handler` as a simple template type.

I mean

```
template <typename F>
bool RegisterCmdHandler (int cmd_id, F sync_handler) {
// ... do something with sync_handler
return true;
}
```

This is a very flexible solution because `F` can be a function, a function pointer, a `std::function`, a lambda (also a generic lambda, so this solution is more flexible than using `std::function`), another type of class/struct with an `operator()`, a value returned from a `std::bind`. In short: a generic callable.

(2) If you can modify the `RegisterCmdHandler()` function **but** you need to know (and use) the `ReqT` and `RestT`, you can follows the plain function pointer way (see Maxim Egorushkin's answer for the syntax). Unfortunately this works with function pointers only and doesn't works (by example) when `sync_handler` is a lambda.

(3) If you can't modify `RegisterCmdHandler()` but you can use C++17, you can use `std::function` deduction guides and call the function as follows

```
RegisterCmdHandler(1, std::function{SomeHandler});
```

or, maybe better if you have to call it in different places, call it through a converter

```
template <typename F>
auto CallRegisterCH (int cmd_if, F && func)
 { return RegisterCmdHandler(cmd_if, std::function{std::forward<F>(func)}); }
```

calling it as follows

```
CallRegisterCH(1, SomeHandler);
```

(4) if you can't modify `RegisterCmdHandler()` and you have to use C++11 or C++14... well... explicating the template types

```
RegisterCmdHandler<Foo, Bar>(1, SomeHandler);
```

seems to me the better way.

Other ways you can explicit the `std::function`

```
std::function<int(int, Foo const &, Bar &)>  sh{ SomeHandler };

RegisterCmdHandler(1, sh);
```

but seems to me almost the same thing.